# How to disable Cursor values on value axis (Yaxis) on amCharts4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have used am4charts.XYCursor(), which shows cursor values on Y & X axes. I wish to hide / disable values showing on Y axis.

```
chart.cursor.lineY.disabled = true;
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/pthakkar/pen/rgLqYY

```
/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

/* Configure cursor lines */
chart.cursor.lineX.stroke = am4core.color("#8F3985");
chart.cursor.lineX.strokeWidth = 4;
chart.cursor.lineX.strokeOpacity = 0.2;
chart.cursor.lineX.strokeDasharray = "";

chart.cursor.lineY.disabled = true;
```

I expect the cursor values appearing on the Y axis (in black background) to disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cursor values are controlled by another properties called [Axis Tooltips](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-tooltips/) and they are configured per axis, and not per cursor (as it would be assumed). Calling:

```
axis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
```

should disable the tooltip. See the modified [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYXBwy) for a working solution.